# Frequency table in Haskell with list comprehension only, find frequency of characters in a String

Tags: list, haskell, frequency, huffman-code

I am new to Haskell, trying to learn some stuff and pass the task that I was given. I would like to find the number of characters in a String but without importing Haskell modules.

I need to implement a frequency table and I would like to understand more about programming in Haskell and how I can do it.
I have my FreqTable as a tuple with the character and the number of occurrences of the 'char' in a String.

```
type FreqTable = [(Char, Int)]
```

I have been searching for for a solution for couple of days and long hours to find some working examples.

My function or the function in the task id declares as follows:

```
fTable :: String -> FreqTable
```

I know that the correct answer can be:

```
map (\x -> (head x, length x)) $ group $ sort
```

or

```
map (head &&& length) . group . sort
```

or

```
[ (x,c) | x <- ['A'..'z'], let c = (length . filter (==x)), c>0 ]
```

I can get this to work exactly with my list but I found this as an optional solution. I am getting an error which I can solve at the moment with the above list comprehension.

```
 Couldn't match expected type ‘String -> FreqTable’
            with actual type ‘[(Char, [Char] -> Int)]’
In the expression:
  [(x, c) |
     x <- ['A' .. 'z'], let c = (length . filter (== x)), c > 0]
In an equation for ‘fTable’:
    fTable
      = [(x, c) |
           x <- ['A' .. 'z'], let c = (length . filter (== x)), c > 0]
```

Can please someone share with me and explain me a nice and simple way of checking the frequency of characters without importing Data.List or Map

Comment: `c` is a function of type `String -> Int`, yet you use in in a context which requires it to be of type `Int` (`c>0`). It seems like you've forgetten to bind a variable: `\list -> [ (x,c) | ... c = length (filter (==x) list) ... ]`

Comment: What does "without importing anything" mean ? List comprehensions use the list monad, ie functions map, concat and guard (hidden by syntactic sugar). Isn't this importing already ?

Comment: Can you please clean up this question? We don't need your life story or what questions you plan to ask later.

Comment: @V.Semeria, that's not actually how they're implemented, although they could be. I think the OP means Prelude-only.

Comment: I meant without Data.List or Map . Even if they're working in the background for the sort and group you have to do the import

Comment: Please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't included what you should be filtering and taking the length of

```
[ (x,c) | x <- ['A'..'z'], let c = (length . filter (==x)), c>0 ]
--                                 ^_____________________^ 
-- this is a function from a String -> Int
-- you want the count, an Int
-- The function needs to be applied to a String
```

The string to apply it to is the argument to `fTable`

```
fTable :: String -> FreqTable
fTable    text   =  [ (x,c) | x <- ['A'..'z'], let c = (length . filter (==x)) text, c>0 ]
--        ^--------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Instead of having text as a parameter can I write = \ text ->   ....... ??

Comment: @PeterPan Why not give it a try?

Comment: On the bus on the way from work :) typing on the phone but will try it straight as I walk home :)

Comment: @Cidec Do you have any suggestions why I am still getting an errore message such as the one below?

Comment: OK I know now is all because of differencw in letters sizes. Can somebody help me how I can change size of letters in my string before I check the frequency? How I can modify this:
\text -> [ (x,c) | x <- ['A'..'z'], let c = (length . filter (==x)) text, c>0 ]
?

Answer (score 1):

The list: `['A'..'z']` is this string:

```
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

so you are iterating over both upper and lower case letters (and some symbols.) That's why you have a tuple, e.g., for both 'A' and 'a'.

If you want to perform a case-insensitive count, you have to perform a case-insensitive comparison instead of straight equality.

```
import Data.Char

ciEquals :: Char -> Char -> Bool
ciEquals a b = toLower a == toLower b
```

Then:

```
ftable text = [ (x,c) | x <- ['A'..'Z'], 
                      , let c = (length . filter (ciEquals x)) text,
                      , c > 0 ]
```